# Unable to compile C Application on mac

Tags: c, xcode, macos

I will need a C developer help who understand's Mac's SDK. I tried to create a c executable with the command

```
./configure --enable-shared
```

I need --enabled-shared in order to redistribute my binary.

I stumble upon this compiler error. Can someone else details on this error message.

```
gcc -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes
-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib Parser/acceler.o Parser/grammar1.o Parser/listnode.o Parser/node.o Parser/parser.o Parser/parsetok.o Parser/bitset.o Parser/metagrammar.o Parser/firstsets.o Parser/grammar.o Parser/pgen.o Objects/obmalloc.o Python/mysnprintf.o Python/pyctype.o Parser/tokenizer_pgen.o Parser/printgrammar.o Parser/pgenmain.o -ldl  -framework CoreFoundation -o Parser/pgen
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "__PyMem_DebugFree", referenced from:
          _PyTokenizer_Free in tokenizer_pgen.o
          _tok_nextc in tokenizer_pgen.o
      "__PyMem_DebugMalloc", referenced from:
          _tok_new in tokenizer_pgen.o
          _PyTokenizer_FromFile in tokenizer_pgen.o
          _new_string in tokenizer_pgen.o
          _tok_nextc in tokenizer_pgen.o
          _PyOS_Readline in pgenmain.o
      "__PyMem_DebugRealloc", referenced from:
          _tok_nextc in tokenizer_pgen.o
          _PyOS_Readline in pgenmain.o
      "__PyObject_DebugFree", referenced from:
          _getgrammar in pgenmain.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    make: *** [Parser/pgen] Error 1
```

My xcode is installed and upto date.

```
$ xcode-select --install

xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

Comment: These linker errors have little to do with Mac's SDK. Have you researched them as linker errors, rather than compiler errors or SDK errors? I suspect your python library is out of date...

Comment: @Seb thanks for the pointer. That was helpful.I could solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a `make distclean` and then ran make with this flag.

`LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib make`

It forced the compiler to look at `/usr/local/lib` and helped me build the shared library.